# TypeError: must be str, not int - in python minesweeper code

Tags: python-3.x

I need help with the following code, because I don't understand what I'm doing wrong.
It's a function for the game Minesweeper which receives a position like "C3" and has to return an int to search a position in a list of available positions.

```
def evalua_jugada(posicion,posiciones_posibles):

    """Convierte a la posicion ingresada en un numero de la lista de posiciones posibles"""

    indice_en_posiciones_posibles = (8 * list(ascii_uppercase).index(posicion[0].upper())) + (posicion[1] + 1) 

    return(posiciones_posibles[indice_en_posiciones_posibles])
```

I'm getting `TypeError: must be str, not int`.

Comment: What is `ascii_uppercase`?

Comment: Is a string module which contains all letters.("A,...,Z")

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`(posicion[1] + 1)` is an operation that requires integers, and because your `posicion` is 'C3', `posicion[1]` is '3' which is a string, not 3, which is a number.

The simplest fix would probably be to use `(int(posicion[1]) + 1)` instead.

Enjoy learning Python!

Comment: That fix the problem. Thanks!